# How to add glow effect to createjs Shape?

Tags: html, createjs

Is it possible to add glow effect to a shape dynamically? as its easy to do so with AS3, I wonder if its supported with easejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Canvas Shadow with 0 offset to achieve this.
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Shadow.html

Note that shadow effects are fairly expensive to draw, and can prevent hardware acceleration.

Cheers.

**[EDIT: Looks like shadow blur does not currently work with Chrome (Mac and PC) when using images.]**

Comment: I tried Canvas Shadow with 0 offset, but how can I expand the shadow size to create outline effect? can I change its size?

Comment: i have an idea, to create another instance of the same image, then apply color filter and scale, place it under ... it will look as an outline around the png image!

Comment: Looks like ShadowBlur is broken in Chrome (Mac and PC), not EaselJS.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with raw canvas APIs. Doesn't work either. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/eUqVm/124/